# Codeigniter and Jquery .load() behaving stangely

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, jquery

So I'm using .load() to call a CI method to load some code into a div like normal. CI loads the correct content into the div UNLESS there is a trailing slash on the class, then it actually ignores the method I am loading and loads the default method in that class ... ie:

THIS WORKS FINE:

I call .load('http://domain.com/class/ajaxmethod')from **domain.com/class/method**

THIS DOES NOT:

I call .load('http://domain.com/class/ajaxmethod')from **domain.com/class/method/**

It will actually load http://domain.com/class/ and ignore the method

Is there something obviously wrong here??

Comment: I tried to simplify the concept here because obviously the relevant code would involve blocks from several areas. Don't want anyone to have to do my work for me :) but I was hoping someone would have a 'gotcha' they've run across using .load() in CI...

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter automatically structures urls like this:

http://domain.com/index.php/class/functions/params

The way you've written the urls in your post (http://domain.com/class/functions/params) implies that you are performing some htaccess rewrite on the url. This is most likely not accounting for the trailing slash and therefore doing something unexpected.

If this is not the case and you've just mistyped your url, can you confirm whether or not the url is correct when visited with a browser and has a trailing slash?